# Would chopping query into smaller views speed thing up?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization, query-optimization

For example, if I have

```
CREATE VIEW viewTest1 AS
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, COUNT(1)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col_a, col_b, col_c

SELECT * FROM viewTest1
```

The other one is

```
CREATE VIEW viewTest2 AS
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c
FROM table_name

SELECT *, COUNT(1) FROM viewTest2
GROUP BY col_a, col_b, col_c
```

Would the second one runs faster? Why?

My test results are the second one is FASTER, which I dont understand.

Thank you

Comment: what rdbms you are using? sqlserver? mysql? oracle? *or what*?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to ask in general or in theory, I dont know there is a difference. I am using SQL server 2008 R2, thank you.

Comment: Did you try to look at the execution plan for both the queries?

Comment: Sorry I know how to bring up the execution plan but I dont know how to read the execution plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) for more detailed analysis Execution Plan

Example:

**Statement1**

```
SELECT * FROM viewTest1
```

[image]

**Statement2**

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) FROM viewTest2
GROUP BY col_a, col_b, col_c
```

[image]

Execution plan both queries absolutely identically. Hence cost both queries equals

You must read this book [SQL Server Execution Plans](http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/sql-server-execution-plans)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the optimizer of the database engine you are using. Some database Engines are capable of reorganizing the whole query, some are not. As far as I know Oracle had a parameter that is controlling the behaviour of reorganization.

So there will never be a single answer in theory.

Answer (score 1):

there can't be a such different. however you can check the execution plans for further cost details.

you may put both queries is same sql window and just press `CTRL+L` keys for the execution plans.

Comment: Sorry I know how to bring up the execution plan but I dont know how to read the execution plan

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample set of data with over 200k rows in the table and the execution plans are identical.

[image: Execution Plan]